# Camera preview won't close after picture is taken. Android custom camera

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, image-capture

I was following the android docs on how to implement a custom camera. Everything works fine, but after I take a picture the preview won't close. In turn the picture is written to disk.

I have tried to call when the shutter is pressed but nothing happens:

```
if (mCamera != null) {
             mCamera.stopPreview();
             mCamera.release();
             mCamera = null;
         }
```

Thanks!

Camera Activity:

```
package com.fideli;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

        protected static final String TAG = null;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private CameraPreview mPreview;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 0;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            getActionBar().hide();
            setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview_layout);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x; 


            // Gets linearlayout
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);
            // Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
            LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
            // Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
            params.height = width;


            // Create an instance of Camera
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();

            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }



    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }



    public void takePicture(View view){
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        System.out.println("picture taken!!");
        if (mCamera != null) {
         mCamera.stopPreview();
         mCamera.release();
         mCamera = null;
     }
    }


    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }


    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " );
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };



    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


}
```

Camera Preview:

```
package com.fideli;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;

        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
                Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
         if (mCamera != null) {
             mCamera.stopPreview();
             mCamera.release();
             mCamera = null;
         }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you try and move the camera releasing block

```
if (mCamera != null) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
```

inside of `onPictureTaken(...)` method if you don't see the printout of `System.out.println("picture taken!!");`

Check this out [Ultimate Android Camera Guide](https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide)

Also, I suggest using [Log API for sending log output](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of System.ou